# Printing on Gimp A4 paper

Tags: print-design, gimp

Hi when trying to print on an A4 paper while using gimp I get margins on the side, top and bottom while i want my image to fill the whole A4 paper pls pls help me print

Comment: This is a tech support question and the answer depends on the model of your printer. Many printers aren't capable of printing edge to edge.

Comment: Edge to edge is frequently doable, but top/bottom less so due to paper traction. Plus you image would need to have the right aspect ratio: 1:1.4142 .

Answer (score 0):

If your printer can not print all the way, you simply can not.

This space is normally used for two reasons.

1) Grab the paper.

2) Have a safe margin so the ink does not get spilled out o the page.

There are a few printers that can print all the way, but normally things are printed on a bigger paper and then the excess is trimmed away.

Answer (score 0):

Yo there, when you select the File > Print , you get a module like this
[image]

So in the general tab select the size and type of paper used and right in the image settings tab you can change the X, Y resolution to fill it the way you want, besides in the advanced tab you can select to reduce or enlarge the image by percentage (fit or shrink).

Be careful, depending on the driver of the printer you are using is the real area of printing, so check that you are not cutting some part of the image when printing at full size!   Check the preview too, is useful.
Cheers!!